# Move workdir to another drive and set max size

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops

Documentation is extremely scarse on this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts#download-configure)

How to install VSTS agent on C, but keep workdir on other drive?
How to force VSTS agent to reclaim space or limit agent to X gb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's able to change the working directory to another driver.

For the new build agent, when you run `.\config.cmd` command, there is a step called:

`Enter  work folder (press enter for _work):`
You could change the path here.

> The default work folder location is a `_work` folder directly under
>   the agent installation directory. You can **change the location to be
>   outside of the agent installation directory,** for example: `D:_work`.

For a existing build agent, you could [remove and re-configure an agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts#remove-and-re-configure-an-agent). Delete the old working folder will not break the agent.

You could refer this [blog](https://johandorper.com/log/) as a tutorial(*For TFS but similar to VSTS*).

---

`How to force VSTS agent to reclaim space or limit agent to X gb?`

You could not do this for local agent. There is no such setting in agent capabilities.

If you need this feature, [Hosted agents offer 10 GB of space.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/hosted?view=vsts#capabilities-and-limitations)

If you are worrying about the disk space:

1. By setting the `Build.Clean` variable to all, it will clears the directories before pulling sources.
2. Use "Delete Files" utility task. The `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` and `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`variables are useful for this. It will delete files after built successfully.

For more info please refer: [Clear the work folder after each build?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/708)

Comment: is it safe to remove the workdir? i want to place the workdir on temp SSD drive on Azure.

Comment: ok, i guess you misunderstood me. my question is what happens if the directory is gone after the vm is reboot. wiil the agent freak out?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Sorry for the misunderstanding. **This will not influence the agent.** Just had a simple test locally, when the build agent is not running, delete the entire _work folder on the build agent, trigger a new build ,  TFS will auto create a new `_work` folder in this case and the build runs successfully. It should be some as your SSD drive on Azure. The agent will not freak out. You could test and double confirm in your environment.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to change it is by going to the agent folder, show all the hidden files.
you'll find a JSON file ".agent" open it, specify the path to your desired directory in "workFolder".

Don't forget to use escaping with the double slashes \, also the agent must be stopped before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

When you install the agent it will ask you for the working directory. The default is _work under the agent install folder, but you can change this at setup time.

You can not limit agent to use X space, but you could add a build/release task to check available space using powershell and fail the process if it is under Y.

**Updated**

This task could be your first build/release task, so you would not go far in the process if there was not enough space.

Comment: You may need to run `tf workspace /delete` to remove any TFVC workspace mappings on the server. After that you can safely blow away the existing folders when the agent is shut down..

Comment: well, I'm talking about VSTS, not TFS @jessehouwing

Comment: In VSTS you can also have TFVC repositories. This is not a TFS vs VSTS thing.  If you're only using Git repositories you can simply clean out the work folder. Your next few builds will likely be slower though, as the agent will need to fetch the repositories from scratch again.

Comment: ah, ic what you meant. I dont care about that, I only care about if it breaks the agent @jessehouwing

Comment: Yes it is safe to completely delete your work folder. The agent will create it agent on first run.

Comment: It may break the agent, I've had issues with it not being able to recreate workspaces in the past.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use junctions links e.g. running this in CMD (replace folders with real locations for you):

```
mklink /J "C:\agent\_work" "D:\agent\_work"
```

Now, _work folder will actually be on D: drive, but the agent will think it is a real folder on C:.
I tested it myself, working fine.